# File dialog from JavaScript *without* <input>

Tags: javascript, file, dialog

I am adding file import functionality to an existing page.

I want to do this using javascript and without modifying the page, ie. without adding the "input type="file" " tag, everyone seems to be talking about.

I have added the button, now I want the event to show the file dialog, user to browse for file and javascript to submit file to server for validation.

How do I do that? 
Btw, main priority is opening file dialog, so no need for user or submitting part, if you don't know it.

Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if I understand correct what you want, is some like this...

```
<input type="button" value="Add File" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click()" />
<input type="file" id="file" style="display:none" />
```

Hidding the `file` object and calling the file dialog with another object. Right ?

**EDIT: Only Javascript**

```js
myClickHandler() {
    var f = document.createElement('input');
    f.style.display='none';
    f.type='file';
    f.name='file';
    document.getElementById('yourformhere').appendChild(f);
    f.click();
}

button.onclick = myClickHandler
```

Put this in your object with the `id` of your `form` in place of `yourformhere` !!

Comment: Something like that, yes, but preferably without having to use any tags at all. I am coding on top of an existing application, and am not currently allowed to alter the sites too much.

Comment: dom elements do not have a method "click"

Comment: Thx. Used your javascript as inspiration and came up with:
var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.setAttribute("id", "importFile");
  element.setAttribute("type", "file");
  element.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;");
Then added click-event in calling method and dialog pops up :-)

Comment: @I.devries checking now I see that it just doesn't works in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Here's is a way of doing it without any Javascript and it's also compatible with every browser, including mobile.

---

BTW, in Safari, the `input` gets disabled when hidden with `display: none`. A better approach would be to use `position: fixed; top: -100em`.

---

```html
<label>
  Open file dialog
  <input type="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em">
</label>
```

If you prefer you can go the *"correct way"* by using `for` in the `label` pointing to the `id` of the input like this:

```html
<label for="inputId">file dialog</label>
<input id="inputId" type="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em">
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
export function pickFile(onFilePicked: (file: File) => void): void {
    const inputElemenet = document.createElement('input');
    inputElemenet.style.display = 'none';
    inputElemenet.type = 'file';

    inputElemenet.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (inputElemenet.files) {
            onFilePicked(inputElemenet.files[0]);
        }
    });

    const teardown = () => {
        document.body.removeEventListener('focus', teardown, true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.removeChild(inputElemenet);
        }, 1000);
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('focus', teardown, true);

    document.body.appendChild(inputElemenet);
    inputElemenet.click();
}
```

And then:

```
pickFile((file: File) => {
    console.log(file);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I hid my first button like this

```
<input style="display:none;" type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
```

The following triggers the input file:

`<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Escoje tu foto de perfil" id="secondbutton" ></i>` (i used an icon)

Which triggers my second button:

```
$( "#secondbutton" ).click(function() {
        $( "#file" ).click();
});
```

From http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Still uses <input>