# Angular 4 TypeScript, click a button to pop file open dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Want to open the standard file open dialog when clicking follow button in the .component.html:

```
<button md-fab md-tooltip="Input">
    <md-icon class="md-24">input</md-icon>
</button>
```

seems the common way to open a dialog is to use input tag like this:

```
<input type=”file”>
```

but it shows extra things on screen. Thinking of do popping up in the .component.ts with a (click) in the :

```
<button md-fab md-tooltip="Input" (click)="onClick()">
    <md-icon class="md-24">input</md-icon>
</button
```

but couldn't find a way to pop up file open dialog in .ts, please help.

@angular/cli: 1.0.1
node: 7.7.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/xxxx: 4.0.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File dialog from JavaScript \*without\* <input>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385758/file-dialog-from-javascript-without-input)

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/1464938) here is simpler. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you are using angular material. Have you tried to follow this example? https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog.
Current code is taken directly from the example in the link.
in the html:

```
<button md-button (click)="openDialog()">Launch dialog</button>
```

And in the .ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example.html',
})
export class DialogResultExample {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {}
}
```