# Browse file in AngularJS + TypeScript on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring, typescript

I have **user.component.html** and **user.component.ts**
All examples I found were in html this way `<input type="file" />`
I don't want to use this style. I have in my html file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" (click)="openPicture()" Browse </button>
```

Below is the function on ts file:

```
  public openPicture() {
    //for testing
    console.log('button clicked to open picture');

    var picture = browse.the.picture.and.assing.to.this.variable;

    //another test, see on console if picture is read
    console.log('%c       ', 'font-size: 100px; background: {{picture}} no-repeat;');
    // Later display picture variable on html and save to database or do anything desired.
}
```

I have found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637202/angular-4-typescript-click-a-button-to-pop-file-open-dialog) on stackoverflow with `angular/material` but I dont have this module. Is there any other alternative way, without installing any extra package to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can implement like this

```
<input type="file" style="display: none" #file (change)="fileChange($event)"/>
<button type="button" class="btn" (click)="file.click()"> Browse </button>
```

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  file: File;

  constructor() {

  }

  fileChange(file) {
    this.file = file.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.file.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I select a file then it gives me file name on console, I want to browse again but then click cancel then I get this error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
" is there a way to prevent this? Also can I specify the browse location?

Comment: 1.  Cannot read property 'name' of undefined "  => you need to check this.file != undefined 
2. Can I specify the browse location? => no , y cant do it

Comment: when I load the same image, nothing happens, any tips? here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473692/browse-the-same-file-again-and-again-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You could try good old hidden input in label:

```
<label class="btn">
    Browse <input type="file" style="display: none;" (change)="handleChange($event)">
</label>
```

`handleChange` implementation would have to consume event:

```
handleChange(event) {
    // consume event.target.files[0] which has File type
}
```

rest about `File` can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Comment: Im kind of getting closer to the solution, I altered the handleChange to `public handleChange(event: MouseEvent) { }` but my Browse button got bigger, inside the Browse button now there is a second button "Choose file" and label "No file chosen". Nothing happens when I click browse but when I click "Choose file" then I can select something. Of course I want only the Browse button to select file.

Comment: have you applied style `display: none` to `input`?

Answer (score 1):

Because of browser security features, you're actually required to use the `input` tag to access the filesystem. What you can do, though, is hide the `input` element and access it from the rest of your code and markup.

Take a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385882/3218168) to get an idea of what you can do. Otherwise, here's a simple example of how it could work:

```
<input type="file" style="display: none" #file/>
<button type="button" class="btn" (click)="file.click()" Browse </button
```

Comment: `file.click()` lets me select a file but then where does this file go? How can I process the selected file or pass it to my own function `openPicture()` ? I want to process the selected file, show it on html and then save to db.