# Browse the same file again and again in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following code on my html

```
<input type="file"  style="display: none" #file(change)="processImage($event)" />
<button type="button"  class="btn" (click)="file.click()"  Browse </button>
```

I choose **image1** from desktop, it is loaded on html by `processImage()` then I delete it with delete button. Then I browse again and choose **image1** again but nothing happens, when I choose **image2**, then it is loaded, afterwards I choose **image1** it is again loaded. In summary choosing the same image again does nothing, probably it isn't a change event. It also makes sense. But for some reason a user may load it again and again after loading and deleting.

How I display the image:

```
<div *ngIf="isImageLoaded" class="showImg"><img [src]="myImage"></div>
```

Any tips to be able to load the same image and fire `processImage()`?

Comment: show your code where you display image, and also on delete image set null value to file input

Comment: I added the code actually I would like to call processImage() on each image load even if it is the same image.

Comment: Can you show the `delete()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear `event.currentTarget.value` as below, I have tried locally and it works fine. whenever you select any image even it repeat always fire `processImage` method.

```
public processImage(event:any):void{
     //your logic    
     event.currentTarget.value='';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, such a simple and sweet solution.